# Spring Data and how to sort by a column not in an Entity

Tags: spring-data, jpql

I'm new to Java Spring and trying to understand how it works as I go.  My goal here is to apply a sort to a JPQL query that is not in an Entity.

References I've been looking at:

[Spring Sort Class Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html)

[Spring Sort crash course](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-six-sorting/)

If I declare the following query

```
@Query("SELECT a, b.someColumn FROM TableA a INNER JOIN a.tableB b where a.search like %?1%"
public Page<Object[]> findSomething(String search, Pageable pageable);
```

This will result in a list of objects with a form of

```
Object[0] = TableA entity
Object[1] = b.someColumn value
```

I've been reading up on the Sort class, but I haven't found a way to make this sort by b.someColumn.

If I do the following

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "someColumn");
Page<Object[]> things = mgr.findSomething("junk", sort);
```

Then the JPQL results in

> SELECT a, b.someColumn FROM TableA a INNER JOIN a.tableB b where
>   a.search like ?1 **order by a.someColumn**

when I want it to be

> SELECT a, b.someColumn FROM TableA a INNER JOIN a.tableB b where
>   a.search like ?1 **order by b.someColumn**

How do I prevent it from appending the sort column to the Entity in the query?  Is there a way to disable this function and make it interpret my sort column literally? Is there a better sorting technique that would be more appropriate to my case?

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "b.someColumn");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it looks like I answered my own question in my original question.  For some reason my browser wasn't up to date with my recent changes and I didn't see the sort working.

The engine will interpret sort columns literally.

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "b.someColumn");
```

Will result in

> SELECT a, b.someColumn FROM TableA a INNER JOIN a.tableB b where
>   a.search like ?1 order by b.someColumn

Which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: doesn't work. "Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property"

Comment: It does work, I've used this method dozens of times.  From the exception, it sounds like it's not able to resolve the sort column you're trying to use.

Comment: sadly, it concats the binded entity alias automatically. "could not resolve property b.b.someColumn". Any ideas? Can you specify the version of your Sping and JPA provider?

Comment: @LovaBill Were you ever able to find out how to specify which entity the sort property would bind to?