# Spring Data JPA sort column not in table/entity

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have query like that:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT new com.domain.ActivityStatistic( " +
        "adm.id, " +
        "adm.fullName, " +
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN (act.action = 'APPROVE') THEN act.action END) AS approved, " +
        "max(act.actionTime) AS lastActionTime) " +
        "FROM Actions act, Admins adm LEFT JOIN adm.group gr " +
        "WHERE adm.id = act.adminId AND act.actionTime BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 AND gr.id = ?3 " +
        "GROUP BY adm.id")
Page<ActivityStatistic> getActivityStatistics(LocalDateTime from,
                                                              LocalDateTime to,
                                                              long groupId,
                                                              Pageable pageable);
```

How can I sort it by the new field that I created: lastActionTime, approved ?
I can run it by native sql in postgresql: pgadmin. But in jpa, when I using sort with field name is approved, it auto become act.approved in JPA query.

I used to read this post [Spring Data and how to sort by a column not in an Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749409/spring-data-and-how-to-sort-by-a-column-not-in-an-entity) but it not help.

Comment: I resolved this problem by using native query, and create new Entity (without create a table) with property: approved, lastActionTime.
And to sort with pageable I using table name instead of table alias name (ex: using admins instead of adm.
And it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply in JPQL on a table column that isn't mapped to a property of an entity.
The reason for this is that JPA including JPQL operates on these entities.

Use a native query instead.